# Retrieve information from Database Using Ajax with Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am just migrating from traditional PHP to Laravel framework using the MVC concept. I want to be able to fetch data from the database based on the  selection made from a dropdown list box. I keep getting this error:
"
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException ".

**See my code:**
Route File:

```
Route::get('/process-grpid','PagesController@processgrpid');
```

my Controller action  code:

```
public function processgrpid($pno){
        $pno = $request->get('pno');
        $det = Stock::where('itemName',$pno)->get();
        return $det;       
    }
```

**my view page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("select.partno").change(function(){
        var selectedPno = $(".partno option:selected").val();
       $.ajax(
           {
               type: "get",
                url:"/processgrpid",
               data:{pno:selectedPno},

               success:function(data){
                  // var det = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#desc").html('<input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Item Description" class="form-control" name="descr" required="required"/>');
               }
            }
        );

    });
});
    </script>


 <table>
     <tr>
              <th>Item Code/Part NO:</th>
                <td>
                <select name="partno" class="partno form-control">
                <option>Select PartNo</option>
                <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                @foreach($pstock as $stock)
                <option value="{{ $stock->itemName }}">{{ $stock->itemName }}</option>
                @endforeach
                </select></td>
                 <th>Description:</th>
                  <td id="desc"></td></tr>
                 <tr>
    </table>
```

I don't know what am doing wrong. I have checked stackoverflow, but non of the soution meet my needs. All i wanted is to get the description of stock item from the database based on the dropdown list of partno. Please, help me look and guide me accordingly .

Comment: Your route is process-grpid when your Ajax is calling processgrpid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a minor mistake in calling route through ajax request.

Change `url:"/processgrpid"` to `url:"/process-grpid"`.

**Reason:** As you defined route as

```
Route::get('/process-grpid','PagesController@processgrpid');
```

So now public url will be `process-grpid` instead of controller function `processgrpid`.

Also update controller function as:

```
public function processgrpid(Request $request) {
    $pno = $request->get('pno');
    $det = Stock::where('itemName', $pno)->get();
    return $det;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Please, how  do i get the description value displayed in the input field :  i have parse the result  like var det = Json.parse(data),    and i can see the Json object with key value paired, how can i display the value in the input field.                                                                                                                                                                            $("#desc").html('<input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Item Description" class="form-control" name="descr" required="required"/>');

Comment: Try this: `$("#desc").html('<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Item Description" class="form-control" name="descr" required="required" value="' + det.label_name + '"/>');` . replace `label_name` with actual label in det variable.

Comment: @Locepreet Singh: I have tried it but it is not displaying anything in the input field.

Comment: I have tried it but it is not displaying anything in the input field. I also added this at the top : var data = JSON.parse(data)

Comment: What is the value in `var data`;

Comment: the response from the query which is Objects with key and value pair

Comment: Can you post that response here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174414/discussion-between-dave-and-lovepreet-singh).

Comment: [{"id":7,"itemName":"52Y56-80301","description":"250X15 RIM ASSY-MONO(TCM)3.5","Rate":"50000.00","createdBy":"admin\r","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]

Comment: It seems like array. So you can access it as `det[0].itemName`.

Comment: Not displaying any value in the input field

Comment: thank you, it works when i change it to data[0].itemName

Answer (score 0):

you should pass `$request` to your controller as below:

```
public function processgrpid(Request $request){
        $pno = $request->pno;
        $det = Stock::where('itemName',$pno)->get();
        return $det;       
    }
```